# RestSharp and List<T> unmarshalling

Tags: c#, restsharp

Hi and thanks for this wonderful tool!

I have a JSON response that returns some 'folders' for an 'account'. I've used http://json2csharp.com/ to generate the classes to serialize the results into. The classes are below this JSON.

The problem, in short, is that the correct folders are returned, and the array is created, however the member variables of the array members (Folders) are never initialized.

```
{
    "name": "SEResponse",
    "declaredType": "com.sesac.api.view.FolderList",
    "scope": "javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement$GlobalScope",
    "value": {
        "link": [],
        "TotalRecords": 9,
        "Folders": [
            {
                "Folder": {
                    "folderId": 1,
                    "accountId": 1,
                    "name": "root",
                    "isRoot": true,
                    "parentId": 0,
                    "parentName": null,
                    "creationDate": null,
                    "lastModifiedDate": null,
                    "fbFolderId": null,
                    "fbParentId": null
                }
            },
            {
                "Folder": {
                    "folderId": 9,
                    "accountId": 1,
                    "name": "m4",
                    "isRoot": false,
                    "parentId": 1,
                    "parentName": null,
                    "creationDate": null,
                    "lastModifiedDate": null,
                    "fbFolderId": null,
                    "fbParentId": null
                }
            },
            {
                "Folder": {
                    "folderId": 2,
                    "accountId": 1,
                    "name": "c1",
                    "isRoot": false,
                    "parentId": 1,
                    "parentName": null,
                    "creationDate": null,
                    "lastModifiedDate": null,
                    "fbFolderId": null,
                    "fbParentId": null
                }
            },
            {
                "Folder": {
                    "folderId": 3,
                    "accountId": 1,
                    "name": "c2",
                    "isRoot": false,
                    "parentId": 1,
                    "parentName": null,
                    "creationDate": null,
                    "lastModifiedDate": null,
                    "fbFolderId": null,
                    "fbParentId": null
                }
            },
            {
                "Folder": {
                    "folderId": 4,
                    "accountId": 1,
                    "name": "cc2",
                    "isRoot": false,
                    "parentId": 3,
                    "parentName": null,
                    "creationDate": null,
                    "lastModifiedDate": null,
                    "fbFolderId": null,
                    "fbParentId": null
                }
            },
            {
                "Folder": {
                    "folderId": 5,
                    "accountId": 1,
                    "name": "dd2",
                    "isRoot": false,
                    "parentId": 3,
                    "parentName": null,
                    "creationDate": null,
                    "lastModifiedDate": null,
                    "fbFolderId": null,
                    "fbParentId": null
                }
            },
            {
                "Folder": {
                    "folderId": 10,
                    "accountId": 1,
                    "name": "z4",
                    "isRoot": false,
                    "parentId": 1,
                    "parentName": null,
                    "creationDate": null,
                    "lastModifiedDate": null,
                    "fbFolderId": null,
                    "fbParentId": null
                }
            },
            {
                "Folder": {
                    "folderId": 6,
                    "accountId": 1,
                    "name": "z2",
                    "isRoot": false,
                    "parentId": 1,
                    "parentName": null,
                    "creationDate": null,
                    "lastModifiedDate": null,
                    "fbFolderId": null,
                    "fbParentId": null
                }
            },
            {
                "Folder": {
                    "folderId": 7,
                    "accountId": 1,
                    "name": "j4",
                    "isRoot": false,
                    "parentId": 1,
                    "parentName": null,
                    "creationDate": null,
                    "lastModifiedDate": null,
                    "fbFolderId": null,
                    "fbParentId": null
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "nil": false,
    "globalScope": true,
    "typeSubstituted": false
}
```

and here are my classes:

```
public class Folder
{
    public int folderId { get; set; }
    public int accountId { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool isRoot { get; set; }
    public int parentId { get; set; }
    public object parentName { get; set; }
    public object creationDate { get; set; }
    public object lastModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public object fbFolderId { get; set; }
    public object fbParentId { get; set; }
}


public class FolderList
{
    public List<object> link { get; set; }
    public int TotalRecords { get; set; }
    public List<Folder> Folders { get; set; }
}


public class RootFolderObject
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string declaredType { get; set; }
    public string scope { get; set; }
    public FolderList value { get; set; }
    public bool nil { get; set; }
    public bool globalScope { get; set; }
    public bool typeSubstituted { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

all your uninitialized objects are of type object.  It looks to me like you'd need to use a more appropriate/specific object type to enable proper de/serialization.  Example: use a DateTime for the timestamp, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the type "object" is a problem (for both the folder and link).

I wonder why you get "Folder" in the JSON though.
I would expect :

```
"Folders": [
            {
                    "folderId": 1,
                    "accountId": 1,
                    "name": "root",
                    ...
            },
            ...
]
```

Using your JSON RestSharp will probably look for a member called "Folder".